# Remote Desktop and ALT-TAB not working

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

A colleague uses the same Remote Desktop connection as I do. He is connecting on his normal OS, I am connecting from a VM. Everything works but one difference: When I do <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> it is done within the Remote Desktop, not on my HOST. When my colleague does <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, it is not done inside the RD, but on the normal OS.

Every time, the RD was selected, not outside the window.

Why does <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> not work on my colleague?

Both OS: Windows 7, both connecting through VPN, same RD, same RD server.

Comment: Do both machines have the same version of Remote Desktop installed?

Comment: Yes, 6.3.9600 on both.

Answer (score 5):

Check that this setting is the same on both RDP Sessions :-[image: RDP Options. local resources tab]

Comment: Did this resolve your issue?

Comment: I have the same issue, and that doesn't resolved the issue.
When I press Alt + Tab, only the Tab is applied.